# How to consolidate multiple Excel sheets into one? Looking for a Powerquery, non-VBA solution. Sheet structure similar but not identical

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a number of Excel files, all with tables on multiple tabs (sometimes more than 100), and I need to consolidate them into a single sheet.

I typically do it with Python and pandas, which I find very efficient, but is there a way to do it in Excel? I ask because, ideally, some of my colleagues, who will realistically never learn Python, would need to do it themselves.

Ideally I would like a solution with PowerQuery / Get & Transform, and not based on VBA, which I find very antiquated and inefficient (plus those who'll never learn Python will never master VBA, nor that anyone should in 2020).

There are many Powerquery tutorials online, but they are all for cases where each table in each tab has the same structure and has been formatted into an Excel Table. My files are not like that, and if I were to manually "format as table" 100 times it would be a very thankless task.

**My complications are that**:

- there are no named Excel Tables in the file;
- the structure of the tables is similar but not identical; most fields are the same, but some fields are only present in some tables, and some fields are in a different order (eg column Month may be in column D in one table but in column F in another);
- some tables have text comments at the top and bottom, which I need to get rid of after the consolidation (I mean text entered into cells, not commented cells)
- the name of the tab needs to be added into a column in the consolidated result, eg I need to be able to identify that one row came from the tab "New York" while another came from the tab "Tokyo"

### Note on duplicates

I am fully aware that this can be done in Python (I already do it), that there are many questions on how to do it in VBA (I am looking for a non-VBA solution) and that there are many Powerquery tutorials (for which the data is already in Excel Tables and always with the same identical structure), but my question is different.

Answer (score 1):

See below. This would consolidate all tabs on all spreadsheet files in specified directory. There is no way to know how to remove the text comments at the top of each table, which will throw this method off, since you did not provide any examples to work with, so I will leave that exercise to you

PS This similar question has been answered multiple times by multiple people (including myself) on this site as well as others

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Do you have a link to such answers or other online tutorials? I must have spent about an hour searching stackoverflow and the web in general, and, like I said, all I could find were VBA solutions or powerquery solutions where the tables were identical and already converted into Excel tables. Thank you.

Comment: well, for me, among others, you've got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173987/how-to-combine-different-sheets-into-one-file-given-the-numbers-of-sheets-always/62194559#62194559 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453719/how-can-i-combine-the-first-two-rows-in-52-files-as-a-header-row-and-combine-all/63458921#63458921